# Python: Remove Node Linked List

Tags: python, linked-list

I am fairly new to Python and am trying to delete a node from a Linked List (not the tail) and am getting the error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'. Clearly, something is wrong with `delete_middle_node`, but I'm not understanding what!

EDIT: complete error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delete_middle_node.py", line 48, in <module>
    delete_middle_node(middle_node)
  File "delete_middle_node.py", line 35, in delete_middle_node
    if not node.next:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Here's what I have:

```
class Node(object):
    """Class in a linked list."""

    def __init__(self, data, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList(object):
    '''Linked List using head and tail'''

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def list_print(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            print node.data
            node = node.next

    def add_node(self, data):
        '''Add node with data to end of list.'''

        new_node = Node(data)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node

        if self.tail is not None:
            self.tail.next = new_node

        self.tail = new_node

def delete_middle_node(node):
    if not node.next:
        raise ValueError('Cannot remove tail node')
    node.data = node.next.data
    node.next = node.next.next

ll = LinkedList()
ll.add_node(300)
ll.add_node(20)
middle_node = 50
ll.add_node(middle_node)
ll.add_node(10)
ll.add_node(15)
delete_middle_node(middle_node)
ll.list_print()
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: `middle_node` is an int, `50`, not a `Node`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`middle_node` is an integer. You're passing it to `delete_middle_node` which expects a `Node` object.

You can fix it like this:

```
class LinkedList(object):
    '''Linked List using head and tail'''

    ...

    def add_node(self, data):
        '''Add node with data to end of list.'''

        new_node = Node(data)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node

        if self.tail is not None:
            self.tail.next = new_node

        self.tail = new_node

        # returning the newly created Node object
        return new_node

...

middle_node = 50
mid_node = ll.add_node(middle_node)
...
delete_middle_node(mid_node)
...
```

Comment: Even though I added it as a node? All of the elements are integers (added as nodes).

Comment: Thank you. I feel like I tried that already, but it totally works now. Appreciate it!